# Converting string to decimal

Tags: c#

In C#, I'm trying to convert a string to decimal.

For example, the string is "(USD 92.90)"

How would you parse this out as a decimal with Decimal.Parse fcn.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going on the assumption here that the string you're trying to parse is an actual currency value.

```
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
c.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 14; // From MSDN -- no enum values for this
c.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "USD";

decimal d = Decimal.Parse("(USD 92.90)", NumberStyles.Currency, c);
```

Comment: +1, I didn't know about passing the NumberStyles.  I'd still use TryParse though (I notice it takes the same parameters)...

Comment: I like this. Although what if the Currency changes?

Comment: @LB: If you're dealing with multiple currencies, I'd parse them each one at a time. Since the values themselves aren't really comparable to each other (i.e., USD$15 != CAD$15), it's somewhat meaningless to put all of them in a single array, for example.

Answer (score 6):

You could start off with a reg-exp to extract the number part and then use Decimal.TryParse to parse the sub-string.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the number out of the string. A Regex `\d+(.\d+)?` might help there. Although you could use substring, if the characters around that number are always the same.

Then use Decimal.Parse (or Double.Parse) on that string.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing strings, I always prefer to use TryParse to avoid exceptions being thrown for invalid strings:

```
        string str =  "(USD 92.90)";
        decimal result;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(str, out result))
        {
            // the parse worked
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid string
        }
```

And as others have said, first use a regular expression to extract just the numerical part.