# De-Format Currency in C#

Tags: c#

I have a string value coming from a label in the .aspx page as following.

```
string text = Price.Text; // Price.Text = "$31.07"
Single value = Convert.ToSingle(text); //throws FormatException
```

I can replace the $ sign with the empty text and then Convert to Single but I was wondering if there is better way to de-format the text with the '$' sign into a Single.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636985/converting-string-to-decimal

Comment: Single is the wrong data type to use for money; use Decimal instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following instead:

```
string text = Price.Text; // Price.Text = "$31.07"
Single value = Single.Parse(text, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Comment: This will work if USD is the computers native currency (or if you set the numberformat for your running thread).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you remove the "$" as you suggest, and then use `Single.Parse()` to convert the string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
string text = Price.Text;
text=text.Replace("$","");
Single value = Convert.ToSingle(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

If USD is your computers native currency you can use:

```
Single value = Single.Parse("$31.07", NumberStyles.Currency);
```

If it's not I would go for the stripping.

Answer (score 0):

With alternate cultures:

```
decimal.Parse("£12,345.67", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
decimal.Parse("€12.345,67", NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```